# Can PowerShell update the content of a Text web part?

Tags: azure, powershell, text, sharepoint-online, web-parts

I would like to use a PowerShell script to amend the content of a Text web part in one of our SharePoint Online sites, but I don't see anything in SharePoint PnP, nor in M365 PowerShell that will enable this.

Does anyone know if this is even possible, please?

Comment: Have you searched if there's a REST API?

If yes, you can find examples of calling REST APIs from PowerShell.

Comment: Hi @BernardVanderBeken

I see list and folder operations in the REST API, but nothing to do with retrieving and updating a web part, unfortunately.